# how to move a button and see it with effect/animation methods using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normaly when i want to make some kind of effect in jquery i take the desiered element, fade it out and  use, appendto(), insertbefore(), insertafter()...and fade in the element at it's new position.

Ive been researching for a while now and have not been able to find how i can do this move and see it in action(visualy). I am aware of the animate function that is included in jquery but i can't figure out how i can actually append the elment that i move to the new container div.

example:
i want to move a button from one container div to another and i want to see this move in action. Keep in mind that when the element lands in the new container div it has to be inside of this container and not just positioned at the desiered position in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: You could implement the following: compute the absolute source and destination offsets of the element, then position the element absolutely and warp it to its source offset, then animate it to its destination offset, then position it statically and append it to its new container. As you can see, that's doable, if not trivial.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I did not even consider offset and changing the position to absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Frédéric Hamidi I was able to figure this out. Here is my solution:

I have an upload handler on my page, and before I upload the image I show a preview of that image with a `fadeto` function. Inside of this `fadeto` function I created an `animate` function that gave me my desired result.

```
$("#fileImageContainer").fadeTo(500, 1, function() {
    var btnPosition = $(".uploadBtn").offset();
    var imgPosition = $("#fileImageContainer").offset();
    //imgPosition.left += $("#fileImageContainer img ").width();
    imgPosition.top += $("#fileImageContainer img").height() + 30;
    $(".uploadBtn").animate({
        "left": "+=" + (55 + imgPosition.left - btnPosition.left).toString() + "px",
        "top": "+=" + (imgPosition.top - btnPosition.top).toString() + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 1500,
        complete: function() {
            $(".uploadBtn").removeClass("detachElement");
            $(".uploadBtn").appendTo("#fileImageContainer")
            $(".uploadBtn").text("Add new");
        }
    });
});
```